# Passing "python2.7 -c" output as parameter for C file

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line, parameters

Outside of a debugger, I'd like to pass through something ran in python. I can do this easily in something like GDB.

example:

```
./a.out python -c "print 'A'*100"
```

Note that this did not work:

```
python -c "print 'A'*100" | ./a.out
```

Comment: Reading from standard input is the job of the program you're piping to.

Comment: `python -c "print 'A'*100" | ./a.out` means that you are passing the Python code's output *to the standard input* of `a.out` (i.e., something that would be read by `fgets()`, `scanf()` etc. in your code), **not** the command line. As you discovered, backticks allow you to interpolate the output into the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I've figgured it out. Using the slanted quote.

```
./a.out `python2.7 -c 'print "Hey"'`
```